# Android Handler.handleMessage() won't get called

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler, runnable

I'm trying to understand this version of `Message.obtain()`
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html#obtain%28android.os.Handler,%20java.lang.Runnable%29

The Runnable passed to Message.obtain() is called for sure,
but the Handler.handleMessage() defined is not called (on msg.sendToTarget() or even mHandler.sendMessage(msg))

```
Handler mHandler;

class MyThread implements Runnable {

  @Override
  public void run() {
    Message msg = Message.obtain(mHandler, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("This is printed for sure"); // This is printed for sure
        }
    });

    msg.obj = "My message!";

    msg.sendToTarget();
  }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  mHandler = new Handler() {
      @Override
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
          System.out.println(msg.obj); // This is never printed
      }
  };

  Thread t = new Thread(new MyThread());
  t.start();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean to do `new Thread(this)` instead of using `new Thread(new MyThread())`?

Comment: Why do you think that handleMessage should be executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let' s take a look at this method from `Message` class:

**public Runnable getCallback ()**

> Retrieve callback object that will execute when this message is
>   handled. This object must implement Runnable. **This is called by the
>   target Handler that is receiving this Message to dispatch it. If not
>   set, the message will be dispatched to the receiving Handler's
>   handleMessage(Message)**.

and what you have called to obtain a `Message`

```
public static Message obtain (Handler h, Runnable callback)
```

So because you set the callback  `handleMessage(Message)` is not called :-)